# from unique_ptr<char[]> to unique_ptr<const char[]>

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, unique-ptr

What's the best idiom to move a `unique_ptr<char[]>` to a `unique_ptr<const char[]>`?

Use case: suppose you create a C string in some buffer. To ensure proper cleanup in case of an exception, that buffer could be references using a `unique_ptr`. Once the string is constructed, you might want to move it to some class member, which is declared `unique_ptr<const char[]>` to avoid further modification of the string.

Here is the best I have so far:

```
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> res;
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[4]);
buf[0] = 'f';
buf[1] = buf[2] = 'o';
buf[3] = '\0';
res = std::unique_ptr<const char[]>(const_cast<const char*>(buf.release()));
```

Simply moving doesn't seem to work, probably due to the different deleter types. Even omitting the explicit cast from `char` to `const char` does not work, as discussed in [Should `unique_ptr< T const [] >` accept a `T*` constructor argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8531246/1468366)

Is there any better idiom to achieve what I outlined above? My code looks pretty clumsy and rather lengthy considered how simple the concept sounds at first.

Comment: Using just `res = std::move(buf);` compiles fine for me in VS2010 and VS2012 and Clang trunk (with libc++ trunk). GCC 4.7.2 chokes on it, though.

Comment: It seems GCC 4.8 trunk fixed the problem and you can use `res = std::move(buf)` there too. Otherwise, I don't think you can get around this cast thing. You can shorten the line to `res.reset(const_cast<char const*>(buf.release()));`, though.

Comment: @Xeo, both the information on GCC 4.8 and the shorter idiom using `reset` are very valuable. Please post them as an answer.

Comment: I know of one better way: to use a `std::string`. Just don't copy it around, and it'll move just fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm assembling the return value for an override of `std::exception::what()` which has to be `const char*`. I did most of the work on `std::string`, so `buf` is the character array I'm assigning to, and `res` is a member which I use to keep the result alive until the exception itself gets collected. I guess I could instead return the result of `std::string::c_str()`, I guess. Getting the class to not manipulate that string can't be enforced though, as there is no `std::string` which can be assigned to but not modified in place. Which makes my whole issue here not applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS2010 and VS2012's stdlib allow conversion with `res = std::move(buf)` as an extension and as a response to [DR2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3516.html#2118). Same goes for libc++ and GCC 4.8's libstdc++.

For GCC 4.7, you won't get around the `const_cast`, but atleast you can shorten the line somewhat:

```
res.reset(const_cast<char const*>(buf.release()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Smart Ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html) library of Boost has generic pointer cast functions that work with the smart pointers from that library as well as those from STL. In particular, [`const_pointer_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#pointer_cast_const_pointer_cast) can do what you need:

```
#include <boost/pointer_cast.hpp>

// ...
res = boost::const_pointer_cast<const char[]>(std::move(buf));
```